# How to select the load shape class from command line?

Tags: python, testing, load-testing, locust

The standard Locust's way to apply custom load shapes to user classes is by defining the load shape class inside the Locust file (a Python module) that contains the user classes. This mechanism is not flexible.

Example: the following command starts a Locust test using the specified file `locustfile.py`:

```bash
locust -f locustfile.py
```

Inside the `locustfile.py` you may have one or more user classes defined.

Now I want to apply a custom load shape to user classes from the command line. How to do that?

Copy of the Locust documentation:

> Sometimes a completely custom shaped load test is required that cannot
> be achieved by simply setting or changing the user count and spawn
> rate. For example, you might want to generate a load spike or ramp up
> and down at custom times. By using a LoadTestShape class you have full
> control over the user count and spawn rate at all times.
>
> Define a class inheriting the LoadTestShape class in your locust file.
> If this type of class is found then it will be automatically used by
> Locust.
>
> In this class you define a tick() method that returns a tuple with the
> desired user count and spawn rate (or None to stop the test). Locust
> will call the tick() method approximately once per second.
>
> In the class you also have access to the get_run_time() method, for
> checking how long the test has run for.

The text above has been copied from: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/custom-load-shape.html

Answer (score 1):

Right now there is no built in way. But you can work around it using an env var

```
if os.environ[”SHAPE”] == ”big”:
    class BigLoadshape(LoadTestShape):
        ...
else:
    class OtherLoadshape(LoadTestShape):
        ...
```

And then run it like this:

```
SHAPE=big locust … # runs BigLoadshape

locust … # runs OtherLoadshape
```

Another way is by using multiple locustfiles, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73749128/1591921